# Search for a specific string within another string with PHP

Tags: php, string, search, strpos

I need to search a string for any occurances of another string in PHP. I have some code that I've been playing with, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Here is my code:**

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($keyword)) {
  $pos = strpos($location, $val);
  if($pos == false) {
    echo "allow";
    exit;
  } else {
    echo "deny";
    exit;
  }
}
```

---

I have tried some of the options below, but it still does not find the match. Here is what I'm searching:

**I need to find:***

```
blah
```

**In:**

```
http://blah.com
```

Nothing seems to find it. The code works in regular sentences:

```
Today, the weather was very nice.
```

It will find any word from the sentence, but when it is all together (in a URL)  it can't seem to find it.

Comment: It's simpler to use `strstr()` if you don't actually need the substring position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking for boolean `FALSE` in php, you need to use the `===` operator. Otherwise, when a string match is found at the `0` index position of a string, your `if` condition will incorrectly evaluate to `true`. This is mentioned explicitly in a big red box in the [php docs for `strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Also, based on a comment you left under another answer, it appears as though you need to remove the `exit` statement from the block that allows access.

Putting it all together, I imagine your code should look like this:

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($keyword)) {
  $pos = strpos($location, $val);
  if($pos === false) { // use === instead of ==
    echo "allow";
  } else {
    echo "deny";
    exit;
  }
}
```

## Update:

With the new information you've provided, I've rewritten the logic:

```
function isAllowed($location) {
    $keywords = array('blah', 'another-restricted-word', 'yet-another-restricted-word');
    foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
        if (strpos($location, $keyword) !== FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$location = 'http://blah.com/';
echo isAllowed($location) ? 'allow' : 'deny';
```

Comment: How do I check to see if it is a match, instead of false?